# How do I trim the leading zeros in an array of digits without using an arraylist in java?

Tags: java, arrays

I have an array made that represents digits and I am trying to make a method so that if there are zeros in front of the first significant digit I want to trim them, I understand you can't re size arrays so I have created a new array, but my code doesn't seem to run correctly? 
Here is my code I can't figure out what is wrong I've tried everything: (I put stars around the error** It gives an arrayoutofbounds error **)

```
package music;

import java.util.Random;

/**Music Array
 *
 * @author Ryan Klotz
 * @version February 3, 2015
 */
public class Music 
{
    private int length; // length of the array
    private int numOfDigits; // number of actual digits in the array
    int[] musicArray;
    /**Explicit Constructor
     * @param x The length of the array
     */
    public Music(int x)
    {
        length = x;
        musicArray = new int[length];
        Random rand = new Random();
        numOfDigits = rand.nextInt(length);
        int posOrNeg; // determines positive or negative sign
        int digit;
        for (int i = 0; i <= numOfDigits; i++)
        {
            digit = rand.nextInt(10);
            posOrNeg = rand.nextInt(2);
            if (posOrNeg == 0)
            {
               digit *= -1;
               musicArray[i] = digit;
            }
            else
            {
            musicArray[i] = digit;
            }
        }
    }
    public void trimLeadingSilence(Music x)
    {
        while (x.musicArray[0] == 0)
        {
            int[] newMusicArray;
            int count = 0;
            **while (x.musicArray[count] == 0)**
            {
                count++;
            }
            if (count == x.numOfDigits)
            {
                newMusicArray = new int[1];
                newMusicArray[0] = 0;
                x.numOfDigits = 1;
                x.musicArray = newMusicArray;
            }
            else
            {
                newMusicArray = new int[x.numOfDigits - count];
                for (int i = 0; i <= x.numOfDigits - count; i++)
                {
                    newMusicArray[i] = x.musicArray[i + count];
                }
                x.numOfDigits -= count;
                x.musicArray = newMusicArray;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "my code doesn't seem to run correctly"?  Have you tried to debug your code in your debugger?

Comment: Won't it be simpler to ensure the first digits is not zero, then you won't need to trim leading zeros?

Comment: When there is a leading zero it throws the arrayoutofbounds exception

Comment: I suspect there is a bug in your later code so that the array is full of zeros.

Comment: If you pass in a `Music` object with a musicArray of all zeros you're going to get an arrayindexoutofbounds exception.

Comment: Take a look at Arrays.copyOfRange method which will make your job way easier.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `for` loop, use `i < x.numOfDigits - count` (you were using `<=`).

That will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

`i <= x.numOfDigits - count` should use `<` instead. But `Arrays.copyOfRange` is probably a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i <= numOfDigits; i++)
```

Should be

```
for (int i = 0; i < numOfDigits; i++)
```

Currently you are generating 1 more digit than numOfDigits is. This will not give you any exceptions in any case since randInt(length) will be in range of 0 and length - 1.

```
while (x.musicArray[count] == 0)
        {
            count++;
        }
```

Will throw an exception if all values in array are 0.

```
while (count < x.musicArray.length && x.musicArray[count] == 0){
            count++;
}
```

Will fix that for you.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= x.numOfDigits - count; i++)
```

Will also throw you ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException so you should fix it to:

```
for (int i = 0; i < x.numOfDigits - count; i++)
```

Anyway, this is very inefficient since if you have 10 "0" values at the start you are creating 10 new arrays. Take a look at Arrays.copyOfRange method, you should be able to do the same job in less than 10 lines of code.